# Display image from a variable in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image

I'm trying to load a captcha image passing controller to view.The code of my controller

```
    $captcha_data['image'] = $this->captcha_security_model->get_captcha($width,$height,$characters);
//        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
//        imagejpeg($captcha_data['image']);
//        imagedestroy($captcha_data['image']);
    $this->load->view('captcha_view',$captcha_data);
```

Uncommenting that three line showing the image in full page mode.The code of my view:

```
<?php
echo $image;
?>
<img src="" />
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="word"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Loading from view is somehow failed.This code gives me this:

[image]

Comment: what is `captcha_security_model` ? you know codeigniter already has a helper for that ? maybe something is wrong with your model !

Comment: I think `captcha_security_model` is ok. because uncommenting those 3 lines gives me a captcha image.

Comment: then definitely something is wrong with your model , i'm not saying it doesn't return a picture , it's just not that kind of picture that you can put inside html code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass image to the view. Just out put image in 'full page mode' **INSIDE CONTROLLER** and in a view file put something like `<img src='htttp://mysite.com/captchaimage/controller/'>`